# How to fix P0300 and P0304 error codes for Hyundai Accent 2009?

Tags: hyundai, accent, p0300

Make: Hyundai

Model: Accent

Engine: 1.6L

Year: 2009

Error codes: P0300,P0304

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Those are misfire codes. You've likely got a problem with either the ignition or fuel delivery systems (or both).

I would venture to propose that if you "know little about cars" then you are not equipped to diagnose issues with the coils, spark plugs, ignition wires, injectors, etc.

Although I would not usually propose throwing parts at a problem without some investigation as to the root cause, the age of your car means it is likely due for new spark plugs and ignition wires anyway.

I would start with buying a repair manual, then proceed with replacing the plugs and wires as these are common causes of misfires. Injectors and coil pack would be next on my checklist.

Comment: Just from experience, injectors rarely fail on Hyundai's or on most cars for that matter. Fuel pressure? Maybe, unless the fuel pump is weak there's no real restriction point in the system. The most likely causes of misfires are in the ignition system or an engine mechanical issue.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, the most likely cause is spark plugs ($15-$20 for a full set) or coils (about $20 each). A repair manual (Haynes or Chilton) that is specific to your vehicle will cost about $20-$30 and will tell you not only how to do this, but many other repair tasks that you are getting raped for at a mechanic shop, like changing the bulbs for brake lights and turn signals.

The tools needed for this are very rudimentary, and you may have them already. A ratchet with a set of sockets, or a set of wrenches, ideally both. For spark plugs, you will need a spark plug socket, ratchet and ratchet extension. Many "ratchet and socket" toolkits have a spark plug socket included. If you need tools, pawnshops are a great place to get wrenches and sockets.

I've worked on a Hyundai Accent before for this specific problem (I think it was a 2008), you will need to:

1. Remove the plastic engine cover (I think the bolts are 10 mm)
2. Those 4 black things are the coils, twist and yank them out one at a time (they are really on there). Only ever have one of them out of the engine at any given time: each coil goes to a specific plug, otherwise the timing will be completely off and the engine will run like crap.
3. Look into the deep hole in the engine, what you see if the top of the spark plug. Use the spark plug socket, extension bar and ratchet to unscrew it and remove.
4. Set the gap of the new spark plug (you'll need a $3 spark plug gapper tool) and screw it in.
5. Put the coil back in place and move to the next spark plug.

Comment: You may want to use a feeler gauge set (it will come with a little tool to bend the ground strap) to gap plugs those disc things can damage the electrode especially on double platinum or iridium plugs.